# Laravel eager loading withTrashed

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So I have this line `OpportunityController@index()`.

```
public function index()
{
    $opportunities = Opportunity::with([
        'customer',
        'province',
        'createdBy',
        'closedBy',
        'status',
        'checkedLists',
    ])->paginate();

    return new ApiCollection($opportunities);
}
```

All of those related models are using `SoftDeletes` trait. I found out that if those model has been soft-deleted, they will become `null`, and you need to call `withTrashed()`. So this is working.

```
public function index()
{
    $opportunities = Opportunity::with([
        'customer' => function ($query) {
            return $query->withTrashed();
        },
        'status' => function ($query) {
            return $query->withTrashed();
        },
        'province' => function ($query) {
            return $query->withTrashed();
        },
        'createdBy' => function ($query) {
            return $query->withTrashed();
        },
        'closedBy' => function ($query) {
            return $query->withTrashed();
        },
        'checkedLists',
    ])->paginate();

    return new ApiCollection($opportunities);
}
```

But is there a better (shorter / recommended) way to do this, instead of declaring the function repeatedly like this?

I tried `Opportunity::withTrashed([...])->paginate()` and `Opportunity::with([...])->withTrashed()->paginate`, both doesn't work and still return null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare it when you are building your relationship.

```
public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Customer::class, 'customer_id')->withTrashed();
    }
```

Comment: Nice. Still a bit repetitive when other table also has relation to customers and users table, but still far better than my code above.
Thank you very much.